# Script debugger reports "operation not allowed"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a simple project that does some generic array calculations and returns the result in a grid. I needed a short way to scan an array for the maximum value and tried using this:

```
var max = Math.max.bind( Math.max );
var vector_max = Function.apply.bind( max, null );
```

Now, this works great when I am not debugging. But, if I wrap a test function around any statement, like, say:

```
function tester() {
  var r = 0;
  return r;
}
```

..., set a breakpoint anywhere in this function, and click debug, I get an error:

```
"Typeerror: This operation is not allowed. (line XXX, file xxx)"
```

This happens even in a completely new script attached to an empty sheet. Of course, Google has no documentation on their script debugger and no references to any limitations, so, I am totally in the dark.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can also reproduce this. It indeed seems like a bug in the debugger! :)

You should report this in the [Apps Script issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list). And in the mean time use another implementation for your `vector_max` function to debug your code. For example:

```js
function vector_max(a){ return a.reduce(function(r,v){ return r < v ? v : r; }, -Infinity); }
```

Comment: Bug report submitted. And I have a workaround, but the code is much messier. :( I'd bet it's an undocumented design limitation, and not necessarily a bug. These re-referenced function calls are hard to trace and unstack properly, so, they just left it out. I just wish they'd let us know.